# Работа с массивом списков

Tags: c++, list, c++11, vector

Есть список

```
std::list<std::string> list;
std::vector<std::list<std::string> listarray;
// тут заполняем listarray собственно list
```

далее ходим по listarray:

```
for (auto i = listarray.begin(); i != listarray.end(); ++i) {
    // цикл по "массиву" списков
    i - listarray.begin() // позиция
    for (auto k = i->begin(); k != i->end(); ++k) {
        // тут
        if (k == list.begin()){
           cout << *k <<endl;// не выводит 
        }
    }
}
```

Вопрос 1: в комментарии "тут": как получить значение первого элемента списка list?

Вопрос 2: как сравнить итератор с int, типа 
придумал вот это:

```
std::list<std::string>::const_iterator zero_zero{0};
if (k == zero_zero)
```

компилируется, но не работает. Пытался создать переменную с нулем и сравнивать указатели...

Comment: *list.begin()?
list.front()?

Comment: Я думал как-нибудь через оператор []?

Comment: в std::list нет перегруженного []

Comment: Я и смотрю что там описаты только front и back...а, как же со втором элементо, с третьим?

Comment: хождение по списку производится последовательно, с помощью итераторов. Можно сдвинуть итератор на нужное количество элементов с помощью цикла, например, или с std::advance, или еще как - не важно, все равно проход будет последовательным.
std::list::iterator it = list.begin(); std::advance(it, 5);

Comment: `как сравнить итератор с int` - что это за сравнение? Что оно должно давать? Если "индекс" (если для списка можно так выразится), то можно использовать if (k == std::distance(list.begin(), it)), но, конечно же, std::distance будет выполнять последовательный проход по элементам списка, считая насколько второй итератор "впереди" первого.

Comment: Если найдено первое значение списка (индекс 0) то сделать одно действие, если остальные, то другое. В других языках это делается так for(int i=0;i<10;i++){ if (i[0] ==0) {} else {}

Comment: if (it == list.begin()) { /*первый элемент списка*/ }

Answer (score 0):

**вопрос 1:**
с range-based for loop просто обходите вектор, а потом уже берете первый элемент списка

```
  std::list<std::string> list;
  std::vector<std::list<std::string>> listarray;

  for (const auto& list : listarray) {
    std::cout << list.front() << '\n';
  }
```

**вопрос 2:** сравнивать итератор с int не имеет ни какого смысла